# Is there a way to install and remove packages in a single yum command?

Tags: fedora, rhel, yum

Is there a way to add and remove packages at the same time with a single `yum` command? For example, installing postfix and removing sendmail without running two separate commands/transactions.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but I'm not a daily yum user. Why do you want it in a single command?

Comment: @jippie Convenience, mostly. And reducing the time to set up multiple transactions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. Invoking `yum shell` will allow you to specify multiple commands that will happen simultaneously when `run` is entered.

Answer (score 26):

Newer versions of yum also have the `swap` command:

```
# yum swap -- install foo -- remove bar
```

Comment: At least as of now (`yum` on RHEL 7), this can also be written shorter as `yum swap bar foo`.

Answer (score 12):

As the accepted answer already says, you can use `yum shell` to run multiple commands at once, which is fine for interactive use.  But if you want to invoke this command from a script, you can also run it against a file, eg `yum shell translist.txt`, where the file could contain, for example:

```
remove squid
install squid34
run
```

Append the `-y` switch to assume yes to confirmation prompts.

Comment: The `-y` switch gets appended to the `yum shell` command, not to commands _within_ the shell, right? I think (but have not tested) that adding `config assumeyes 1` to the top of the shell commands will have the same effect without needing to change the initial command line.

Comment: yes, `yum shell -y` works for me to make the whole operation non-interactive.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo yum swap postfix sendmail
```

Although the O/P has his answer, I'm leaving this short one for people who need this in the future